# How to find/use a library on system without using Autoconf or Cmake?

Tags: boost, makefile, cmake, configure, autoconf

I have a small project that requires a few standard libraries, say `libpng` and `boost`. For now I hope that project can build easily on any of my collaborators machines (OSX/Unix/**Linux**), but am not concerned packaging or installing it right now. My question is, is there an easy way to write "home-brewed" `Makefile` or `configure` file that can automatically find and use those libraries on a particular *nix system?

I know `Autoconf` and `CMake` are tools designed for such tasks, but I and my collaborators do not want to go into the fuss for such a small project, at least not right now.

Another possibility I have in mind is `pkg-config`. Is that a recommended approach? I currently have two problems with that: (1) it cannot find all libraries, (say `boost`, discussed [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2077), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66720/how-does-gcc-know-where-boost-is-installed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971703/how-to-use-c-boost-library-with-pkg-config)), and (2) not all system seems to have installed `pkg-config`.

The solution I hope to have ishave in mind is to write a `Makefile` that looks like below.

```
INCpng = $(shell command retrieves "-I/path/to/png.h")
LIBpng = $(shell command retrieves "-L/path/to/libpng.so -lpng")

INCboost = $(shell command retrieves "-I/path/to/boost")
LIBpng = $(shell command retrieves "-L/path/to/libboost.so -lboost")

SomeFile: SomeFile.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCpng) $(INCboost) $(LIBpng) $(LIBboost) -o $@ $<
```

I'm also open to write a not-to-complicated `configure` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg-config` was designed for more-or-less exactly this purpose. It was designed to replace the `X-config` scripts/etc. that many projects had been writing on their own before that.

I don't know about `CMake` but I believe the autotools are just using `pkg-config` internally.

For things that `pkg-config` cannot find (and that do not have their own `X-config`) the only thing you can do is use reasonable defaults and allow people to over-ride them (you could test some common alternatives as fallback defaults as well but you still need to allow user over-riding.